# Floating Point Irregularity in Conversion to Integer

Tags: floating-point, ada

I have a routine whose purpose is to encode a floating point number as an integer (it then gets put into a byte stream).  In the process, information is lost. The routine chops the output into increments of 3.33.

So, the gap between 0 and 3.33 is sort of an odd case, because it's not zero, and it's not 3.33. I decided (not totally arbitrarily) that any non-zero floating input should be rounded up to 3.33 (and likewise, 3.34, should go up to 6.66, etc.).

This is all well and good.  The code is as follows:

```
function EncodeFloatingPoint (Value : Long_Float) return Integer is
    Intermediate_Value : Integer;
    Return_Value : Integer := 0;
begin
    -- converts float into 3.33 increments

    -- case 1, positive or zero 
    if (Value >= 0.0) then
        --Ensures rounding away from zero
        Intermediate_Value := Integer((Value * 100.0 + 332.99) / 333.0); 

    -- case 2, negative through -3.33 (up to, but not including zero)
    else

        -- Code omitted, is not problematic
    end if;

    Return_Value := Intermediate_Value;

    return Return_Value;
end
```

The issue happens when I pass the value `0.0` in to my code during a unit test. When stepped through, the conversion results in a value of `3.33` rather than the expected `0.0`, and my unit test fails. However, when I go to the GDB console and type `Print Integer((0.0 * 100.0 + 332.99) / 333.0)`, the result is 0 as expected (substituting `0.0` for Value).  I can confirm that Value prints out to 0.0.

What could be going on? Is there a simpler way to ensure rounding away from zero when converting this back to an Integer?

Comment: equals comparisons with float are not going to work the way they work with fixed point.  you might try if not negative, but for one/some floating point formats negative zero is possible.

Comment: It's not an equals problem - the value going through the conversion is 3.33 and it prints out that way. I just don't understand why.

Comment: your value is not zero most likely, add a case of value = zero separate from the others, see if you are in fact falling into it or not.  there are many layers to this, there are libraries used by the compiler, libraries and code used by gdb.

Comment: IEEE-754 has multiple rounding modes available, up down, toward zero, etc.  but does every language support those?  and if so how to specify those rounding modes?

Comment: It's a unit test, and the value is specifically initialized to `0.0` -> the `.0` is required by the compiler. We're using gcc.

Comment: you are misunderstanding what i am saying I thought this question was about I get two different results when I do math with zero.  that is what I am commenting on.  perhaps you are asking a different question.

Comment: Smells like an XY problem ... why 3.33 and not 10.0/3.0 for example? And why add 332.99 instead of 333 - epsilon? There's something funny here. I'll look at it tomorrow, but I wonder if this task is something that would be better handled by fixed point? (But I don't know the problem constraints.

Comment: @Brian Drummond - it’s an external interface. This is part of the bit packing.

Comment: If I add 333, then a value of zero would bump the division up to 1.0 and would return 1 as an int as opposed to zero (Ada floors integer conversions above zero).

Comment: Please don't use the predefined floating point types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the [Language Reference Manual](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-TOC.html), you will see that floating point types have an attribute function `'Ceiling`, which yields the "smallest (most negative) integral value greater than or equal to X" (the passed parameter).

So try: `Rounded := Floating_Point_Type'Ceiling (Not_Rounded)`

Comment: This got the job done, although I'm still curious to know why passing a `0.0` in at the debug console produces the expected output, while it does not produce the expected output when a constant `0.0` is passed in from the compiled code...

Comment: I can't answer that.  But I don't think anything requires the compiler to use exactly the same version of zero for `0.0` listed in source text and `0.0` parsed by `Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO`.

Answer (score 5):

You're calculating `332.99 / 333.0`, which is about 0.99997. Conversion from real to integer types rounds [ARM 4.6(33)], so you get 1. I presume you're interpreting that as 3.33. You're probably going to have to special case zero:

```
if Value > Long_Float'Pred (0.0) and Value < Long_Float'Succ (0.0) then
   return 0;
end if;
```

(Note that parentheses are not needed around the condition of an "if" statement.)

You might also find the `'Remainder` attribute function useful. You should be familiar with all of the floating-point attributes in ARM A.5.3 (indeed with all of the standard libarary in ARM A).

It appears that you're creating your own fixed-point type with a small of 3.33. Why not let the language do that for you?

```
Result_Delta : constant := 3.33;

type Result_Value is delta Result_Delta
   range Integer'First * Result_Delta .. Integer'Last * Result_Delta
   with Small => Result_Delta;
```